# read Xml file form a zip file using php

Tags: php, zip

I have a zip file which have one folder named Objects. Inside Objects folder I have one Xml file. I need to get data from that xml file using PHP.

I tried following code

```
$file = 'file.zip';
$path = pathinfo(realpath($file), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo($path);
  $zip->close();
  echo "WOOT! $file extracted to $path";
} else {
  echo "Doh! I couldn't open $file";
}
```

But it returns an empty folder named Objects. The xml inside the folder is missing.

Can anybody tell me What I am missing?

Comment: It seems that you're trying to extract to the current location of the zip file, which probably means you're overriding the zip file as you're trying to inflate it...

Comment: Your code works for me as is. Is it a password protected ZIP or something rare?

Comment: It is not a password protected zip. we can simply unzip it from windows. but when we do it using above code it returns an empty folder.

Comment: from php manual i used unzip function. link  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php . Itshowing "Unable to open zip file "